# Enumerating through a JS array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

OK jQuery experts : So .. I'm coming from a Prototype background.

I do the following code all the time (or some similar variation):

```
MyObject.prototype.someFunction = function()
{
  var myArray = ["a","b","c"];
  myArray.each(function(arrayEntry)
    {
      this.printPart(arrayEntry);
    }, this);
}

MyObject.prototype.printPart = function(part)
{
  console.log(part);
}
```

I'm looking through the jQuery docs -- I don't see how to do this.

Is this possible?

In particular, I'm interested in:

- Iterating through javascript arrays (objects would be nice too).
- Maintaining scope.  Notice the final "this" parameter to the each function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for `$.each(array, function(i, element) { ... })`

That also handles objects, in which case you get `(key, value)` in the arguments.

*edit* — sadly there's nothing like Prototype's `inject`, and I really miss that a lot. But there's `map` in jQuery and that's kind-of like `collect` in Prototype.

*edit again* — As @Nick points out in his comment, Prototype and jQuery disagree as to the best way to deal with handling "this".  Generally, jQuery invokes "handler" functions with "this" pointing to the obvious relevant object. Prototype is more hands-off as far as that goes.

Comment: +1 - Though you'll need to store what `this` is (unlike prototype), since `$.each()` creates a closure where `this` is the current element in it's callback.

Comment: @Nick yes indeed, that's true. It's actually kind-of amazing how different are the programming styles imposed by those two libraries. That's why I generally moan and roll my eyes when somebody asks how hard it'll be to "convert a site from Prototype to jQuery" ...

Comment: Hey also, if you really miss those Prototype things, check out the Underscore.js library - it's made to play nice with jQuery, and it adds some cool stuff.

Comment: @Pointy: That's interesting.  So in the jQuery world, is object scope not so important?  I generally code my javascript to be very similar to Java, in that I'll have classes with methods.  Calling those methods needs to maintain the correct "this" scope.

Comment: @desau - Actually in this case you'd probably want `$.each(myArray, this.printPart);`, with `printPart` taking 2 params, `(index, part)`, this'll be the most concise way to get what you're after.

Comment: @desau well object scope is pretty fluid in Javascript; in fact one way of thinking about it is that there's really no such thing as "object scope" in Javascript. There's no intrinsic binding between a function object and some other object that happened to be around when the function was defined. Trying to make Javascript act like Java is usually a way to make yourself frustrated and depressed. It's better to think of Javascript as a weird Lisp dialect, almost.

Comment: @Pointy - I see your point.  I guess instead of saying "like Java", I should have said "like an object-oriented language".  But perhaps your comment about getting frustrated and depressed still applies.  Perhaps trying to force a functional language into a OO paradigm is flawed from the start.  Do the jQuery devs generally tend to not architect their client-side in an OO design?

Comment: @desau if you look at it, there's not much about jQuery that you would call "object-oriented". There's no class definition mechanism, no inheritance system, really nothing that you'd expect from an OO framework. (Personally that suits me just fine!)

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily have to do everything in jQuery. Just add a [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/forEach) method if it doesn't already exist, and use that instead. It was so good that ECMAScript 5th ed. adopted it as a standard (inspired by Prototype's each method), but not all browsers have it yet :). Here's an implementation by the spec that you can use until all browsers have it natively ([taken from MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/forEach)):

**Edit**: Latest versions of Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and Opera already support this. No IE access, sorry.

```
if (!Array.prototype.forEach)
{
  Array.prototype.forEach = function(fun /*, thisp*/)
  {
    var len = this.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun != "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in this)
        fun.call(thisp, this[i], i, this);
    }
  };
}
```

Then use your code as it is (change `each` to `forEach`):

```
var myArray = ["a","b","c"];

myArray.forEach(function(arrayEntry) {
    this.printPart(arrayEntry);
}, this);
```